# Nginx - Redirect the rest of the alias domains to a main one in OpenShift

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-headers, 301-redirect, openshift-online-2

I'm trying to redirect permanently a couple of alias domains of an application in OpenShift to a main one for SEO purposes.
The application is running a working instance of [Openshift Nginx Cartridge](https://github.com/boekkooi/openshift-cartridge-nginx).

I currently have:

```
server {
    listen  <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_IP'] %>:<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_PORT'] %>;    

    root    <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'] %>/public;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    server_name appname-domain.rhcloud.com;
}

server {
    listen  <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_IP'] %>:<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_PORT'] %>;    

    root    <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'] %>/public;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    server_name main-alias.domain.com;
}

server {
    listen  <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_IP'] %>:<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_PORT'] %>;    

    server_name _;

    return 301 $scheme://main-alias.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

The returned HTTP headers are:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: another-alias.domain.com
Accept: */*
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2016 00:43:18 GMT
* Server nginx is not blacklisted
Server: nginx
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Location: http://another-alias.domain.com/
```

As you can see, the Location header is not pointing to the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it removing the request_uri variable. But it's not an acceptable answer if the arguments must be redirected.

```
server {
    listen  <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_IP'] %>:<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_PORT'] %> default_server;    

    server_name _;

    return 301 http://main-alias.domain.com;
}

server {
    listen  <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_IP'] %>:<%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_NGINX_PORT'] %>;    

    root    <%= ENV['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'] %>/public;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    server_name main-alias.domain.com;
}
```